# TCP Server, Web Client

Tags: javascript, html, websocket

I have a TCP server which is written in VB.NET. It gets some data from a hardware and it writes this data a SQL server. I want to show some result to users via their web browsers. I have found very nice web client which is written HTML5. But servers which I could find can't communicate properly. (some of servers uses JSON and some of servers don't communicate with my web client)

So, my server send data to web client when there is a change at data. So there will be an asynchronous communicaation between my TCP server and client.

Here is my web client which I found : (I'm sure many of guys know this simple sample)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function WebSocketTest()
{
  if ("WebSocket" in window)
  {
     alert("WebSocket is supported by your Browser!");
     // Let us open a web socket
     var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:7777");
     ws.onopen = function()
     {
        // Web Socket is connected, send data using send()
        ws.send("Test");
        alert("Message is sent...");
     };
     ws.onmessage = function (evt) 
     { 
        var received_msg = evt.data;
        alert(received_msg);
     };
     ws.onclose = function()
     { 
        // websocket is closed.
        alert("Connection is closed..."); 
     };
  }
  else
  {
     // The browser doesn't support WebSocket
     alert("WebSocket NOT supported by your Browser!");
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="sse">
   <a href="javascript:WebSocketTest()">Run WebSocket</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I read some articles about Silverlight can do it but I couldn't find a good sample.

Comment: A web server serves out web pages.  A file server serves out files.  A TCP server serves out....uhh TCP?  This post needs to be clearer.

Comment: @Craig
There is not anything about a file server or something. I just need a solution to communicate between a TCP Server (it's a desktop applicaiton) and web client (i think it will use HTML5 technology but there are another solutions such WebSocketListener too) via WebSocket (or it can be another solution).

My TCP desktop application runs at a Windows Server 2003 machine (because of i know WebSocket runs on Windows 8 but a migration can be possible for my server computer)

Comment: And there will be "text" based interchanging between server and client. And i will change some photos on the client web page.

Comment: Let me be more direct: 1. There is no such thing as a TCP server.  2. To my knowledge, a Web client written in HTML5 does not exist.  Your question talks about things which don't exist.  Thus it is not clear.

Comment: There is a Multithreaded TCP server application which i developed. It works very well. I just need a web client application to communicate with my TCP server. Web client means a web page. Let's assume that there are some photos at web page and i will change this photos according to data which will come from my TCP Server.

I hope everything is clear now.

Comment: You need a web client application, and a web client means a web page.  My brain hurts.

Comment: Here is a good example for web client.
[http://jsfiddle.net/decoder/LPQdQ/](http://jsfiddle.net/decoder/LPQdQ/)

Server uses Fleck socket. This is exactly what i want. I have Fleck server examples but i should implamante such web client but my java script and HTML knowledge is not enough.